# Inserting a unique id into a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with this structure (imagine it could be way bigger than this)

And I need to insert a new item inside, say, 'Name 3' children array. How would I go about creating a unique id for it? I have thought about saving the ids inside the object in a separate array and then creating one that is not on that, but I'd have to maintain it and I'm not sure that would be the best approach?

```js
let obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Name 1',
  parent_id: null,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Name 2',
      parent_id: 1,
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Name 3',
      parent_id: 1,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'Name 4',
        parent_id: 3,
        children: []
      }]
    }
  ]
};
```

**EDIT**: The need for a unique id is for me to be able to delete an item. This is the code I've been given to work with, I can't alter the structure.

Comment: What is the usecase. What is the need for a unique ID, how will you be using it?

Comment: Do you need a numeric id? If not, a valid solution would be to use UUIDs

Comment: Better if you use UUID or Random String along with Timestamp.

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my question. The id is the only thing that makes each item unique. I think UUID could be a solution, thanks for pointing that out.